# PHPBrew unable to install extensions (extension is already disabled for SAPI)

Tags: php, postgresql, phpbrew

I'm new to PHPBrew and Linux (if the OS matters). I've built a PHP 8.2 from PHPBrew and ran a new Laravel project, but I can't connect to database because the driver is missing. Everytime I tried to run `phpbrew ext install pgsql` it returns *pgsql extension is already disabled for SAPI*

How can I enable pgsql or other extensions in PHPBrew in Linux?

I've tried all solutions I could find online but even the official tutorial of enabling extensions didn't work.

This is the full return statement when I tried to install an extension:

```
[ ] pgsql extension is already disabled for SAPI .
===> Installing pgsql extension...
Log stored at: /home/~/.phpbrew/build/8.2-dev/ext/pgsql/build.log
Changing directory to /home/~/.phpbrew/build/8.2-dev/ext/pgsql
===> Phpize...
Error: Command failed: phpize > /home/~/.phpbrew/build/8.2-dev/ext/pgsql/build.log 2>&1 returns:
```

This is the content of the *build.log* file

> Configuring for: PHP Api Version:         20220829 Zend Module Api No:
> 20220829 Zend Extension Api No:   420220829 Cannot find autoconf.
> Please check your autoconf installation and the $PHP_AUTOCONF
> environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

I need to install autoconf on my system (POP OS)

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```